# Не корректно работает нажатие на кнопку в javascript

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь немного упростить себе жизнь и решил написать javascript-код, который при загрузке страницы автоматически заполняет необходимы поля и жмёт кнопку получить расписание. Но проблема в том, что при вызывании события click() у кнопки с текстом "получить расписание", с сервера приходит ответ, что данных он не получил, т.е. насколько я понял, кнопка нажалась, запрос отправился, но данные формы не передались серверу. Как это можно исправить?

Вот javascript-код на странице, который вешает обработчик кнопки:

```js
applySearchToR(document.forms['sform'],'fprep','caf');  
 $('input:button[name = potokbut2]').click(function(){
  $("#zagg").show();
$("#vib").slideUp(1000);
$("#pokaz").show();
 $("#skrit").hide();
var formob = $('#formob :selected').val();
var kyrs = $('#kyrs :selected').val();
var srok = $('#srok :selected').val();
var caf = $('#caf :selected').val();
var cafzn = $('#caf :selected').html();


var sdate_year = $('#sdate_year :selected').val();
var sdate_month = $('#sdate_month :selected').val();
var sdate_day = $('#sdate_day :selected').val();
var fdate_year = $('#fdate_year :selected').val();
var fdate_month = $('#fdate_month :selected').val();
var fdate_day = $('#fdate_day :selected').val();

     //alert("1:"+sdate_day+"."+sdate_month+"."+sdate_year+"---2:"+fdate_day+"."+fdate_month+"."+fdate_year);

$.post(
    '../rasp/3.php', { formob: formob, kyrs: kyrs, srok: srok, caf: caf, cafzn: cafzn, sdate_year: sdate_year, sdate_month: sdate_month, sdate_day: sdate_day, fdate_year: fdate_year, fdate_month: fdate_month, fdate_day: fdate_day },
        function (result1) {                        
              $('#dop2').html(result1); 
 $("#zagg").hide();           
            });

});
```

Вот мой код:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';

    var formob = 'Д', kyrs = '2', srok = 'На сегодня/завтра', caf = '553';

    $('#formob option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == formob) {
            $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('#kyrs option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == kyrs) {
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('#srok option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == srok) {
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
            return false;
        }
    });

    $('#filters').click();

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#caf option').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == caf) {
                $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                return false;
            }
        })
    }, 1000);

    $('input[name=potokbut2]').click();
});
```

Comment: я тут сейчас подумал, может мне просто стоит использовать вышенаписанный код в своём?

Comment: Почему Вы выбираете значение `#caf option` через `setTimeout`? Это значение будет выбрано после клика на кнопку формы...

Comment: там по клику идёт запрос к другому скрипту. поэтому есть небольшая задержка. Если выбрать то значение без задержки, то этих элементов ещё не будет и скрипт ничего не найдёт